# Unable to open media library in Wordpress 4.8

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to open media library when I go via Media -> Library. When I click on Library, I get the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/user1/public_html/wp-config.php on line 95
```

I am however, able to, open uploads folder Media > Upload New . How can I fix this problem?

here is the wp-config.php file https://pastebin.com/3FERAy3U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of crazy errors happened to me once and it seemed like something was added to the code when I uesd Filezilla to upload the file to the server. Here is what helped me:

I opened the wp-config file in notepad (or notepadd++) and removed all the unnecessary blank lines under the line `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` 
I **deleted** the `wp-config.php` file from the server and uploaded the newly created file. This fixed my problem. Please try this and let me know if this solves your problem too.

Comment: fixed by copying wp-config from a clean install of wp 4.8. it works now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Around line 58, there is a missing closing quote (`'`):

```
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xxx);
                             ^^^
```

Should be:

```
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'xxx');
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while pasting. i will try to correct that

Comment: I see, try clearing any additional white-space from the end of the file

Comment: fixed by copying wp-config from a clean install of wp 4.8. it works now. thanks!